# How to change theme on phone programmatically

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, themes

I've been looking around for an answer for this, but seeing as it's not allowed in the Marketplace, I've been flooded with answers regarding how to make theme aware apps. I'm just looking for a code snippet that I can use in a personal app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible in the current version of the APIs.